# Community site are they available inside SharePoint foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

On this link http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint-2013-features-comparison.html it is mentioned that community site are avialable inside; SharePoint Foundation 2013, SharePoint Server 2013 Standard & SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise.

While inside this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219805.aspx link it is mentioned that community site are NOT available inside SP foundation

> “Community Sites are available in SharePoint Server 2013, but not in
>   SharePoint Foundation 2013. However, discussion lists and Web Parts
>   are still available in SharePoint Server and SharePoint Foundation if
>   you want a light-weight discussion experience on your SharePoint
>   sites.”?

So is Community sites available inside SP2013 foundation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not available

Here is the output of Get-SPWebTemplate on a Foundation Farm and there is no `COMMUNITY#0`:

```
Name                 Title                                    LocaleId   Compat
                                                                         ibilit
                                                                         yLevel
----                 -----                                    --------   ------
GLOBAL#0             Global template                          1033       15    
STS#0                Team Site                                1033       15    
STS#1                Blank Site                               1033       15    
STS#2                Document Workspace                       1033       15    
MPS#0                Basic Meeting Workspace                  1033       15    
MPS#1                Blank Meeting Workspace                  1033       15    
MPS#2                Decision Meeting Workspace               1033       15    
MPS#3                Social Meeting Workspace                 1033       15    
MPS#4                Multipage Meeting Workspace              1033       15    
CENTRALADMIN#0       Central Admin Site                       1033       15    
WIKI#0               Wiki Site                                1033       15    
BLOG#0               Blog                                     1033       15    
SGS#0                Group Work Site                          1033       15    
TENANTADMIN#0        Tenant Admin Site                        1033       15    
APP#0                App Template                             1033       15    
APPCATALOG#0         App Catalog Site                         1033       15    
DEV#0                Developer Site                           1033       15    
OSRV#0               Shared Services Administration Site      1033       15    
SRCHCENTERLITE#0     Basic Search Center                      1033       15    
SRCHCENTERLITE#1     Basic Search Center                      1033       15    
GLOBAL#0             Global template                          1033       14    
STS#0                Team Site                                1033       14    
STS#1                Blank Site                               1033       14    
STS#2                Document Workspace                       1033       14    
MPS#0                Basic Meeting Workspace                  1033       14    
MPS#1                Blank Meeting Workspace                  1033       14    
MPS#2                Decision Meeting Workspace               1033       14    
MPS#3                Social Meeting Workspace                 1033       14    
MPS#4                Multipage Meeting Workspace              1033       14    
CENTRALADMIN#0       Central Admin Site                       1033       14    
WIKI#0               Wiki Site                                1033       14    
BLOG#0               Blog                                     1033       14    
SGS#0                Group Work Site                          1033       14    
TENANTADMIN#0        Tenant Admin Site                        1033       14    
OSRV#0               Shared Services Administration Site      1033       14    
SRCHCENTERLITE#0     Basic Search Center                      1033       14    
SRCHCENTERLITE#1     Basic Search Center                      1033       14    
SRCHCENTERFAST#0     FAST Search Center                       1033       14
```

Answer (score 1):

If TechNet says no then it's most likely no. TechNet is run by Microsoft so it would be the authoritative resource in this situation.